# Change number image input channels for BLIP

Tags: image-processing, huggingface

I'm wanting to change the number of image input channels to be larger than 3 using huggingface's BlipForConditionalGeneration. I've tried changing the num_channels in the model's configuration but this doesn't seem to do the trick. Any ideas?

I tried changing num_channels in the configuration but that didn't work.